# How to include jquery-ui library in WordPress?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to load the jQuery UI library into a WordPress plugin using this enqueue statement:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
```

The jQuery library loads fine, but the ui-core is MIA. The only way I can get ui-core functions to fire is to load the library with a static include like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery is enqueued by default on admin side. So, it may not be loading due to your `wp_enqueue_script` statement.
Are you using `wp_enqueue_script` inside some action hook? Because you have to. I use it like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts-options_page-{page}', 'myplugin_admin_scripts' );
function myplugin_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
}
```

Comment: Don't enqueue scripts nakedly in the Admin interface. Use a more specific page hook, i.e. the hook specific to your Plugin's (or your Theme's) settings page.

Comment: Additionally, you shouldn't even need to call jQuery, i believe(and someone correct me if you know otherwise) that jQuery is a dependancy for jQuery UI - so just calling UI on it's own should be sufficient.